# How can I edit this page? Seems to be an issue with Visual Editor?

Tags: mediawiki

I'm trying to edit a page on Gamepedia and I'm getting everything all jumbled up.  Have tried on different computers and browsers, but looks the same.  However, someone else I talked to said it looks fine to them.

Here is the link to the page:  https://battlerite.gamepedia.com/Alysia?veaction=edit&section=4

Comment: Here is how it looks to me:  https://imgur.com/ASrTACB

Comment: Are you able to put everything readers need into the question? Perhaps a JS Fiddle and/or an image? From the close reasons: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**_.

Comment: The file markup is rendered as HTML. Probably an incompatibility between Visual Editor and Cargo. I would be surprised if it was at all browser-dependent.